# Best way to print on paper using a WebService

Tags: php, web-services, ubuntu, printing

**Summary:** Basically, I would like to create an local webservice that can receive text files and print it on paper.

**Why a printing service:** I need that all requests made by a client generate a log on paper. It must be printed on paper without any user confirmation (automatically).

I was thinking to use php (since my webserver is written on PHP). But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627059/406110):

> php cannot easily access hardware. This is generally not considered "possible".

**So, are there alternatives?** PHP is desirable but not obligatory.

*Extra: This printing approach must be customizable, allowing creating a "page template" with e.g. custom margins, colors; and print every time using this template.*

**Edit 1:** Using SO resource, is it more possible? I am using Ubuntu as server.

Comment: This is an awful idea. You should instead have the logs saved to a file and have the queue print on command. You don't want an entire public network to have control over your printer. And you've got to make sure it always has paper. Whatever your doing, I promise there is a better way. But if you're absolutely set on this, consider using Python.

Comment: Just some kind of users could send to the printer. It is a local webservice, running on a local network. (:


1. Queque print is an awesome idea, how can I do this way?

2. What about Python?

Comment: If you're using PHP you can use that the write to the log file using `fwrite()`, then you could use PHP to print your logs with an `exec()` if it must be done remotely or preferably just sit down at the server and hit "print" if it's a local network.

Comment: This may help.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168116/php-server-side-printing-ubuntu-server